# How to select specific values in an array/matrix in Numpy for a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array such as this:

```
data = np.array([[327, 137, 82], [301, 168, 75]])
```

I need to be able to manipulate the individual entries in order to solve the question I am working on. For example, I must be able to sum both rows together, but also add the columns together, i.e. `data[0][0] + data[1][0]`.

However, I want to write a function that allows me to do this with any size array `n` x `m`.

I have tried something such as:

```
for x, y, z in data:
    etc.
```

But I can't pull the specific element position that I want. My goal is to write a more general/abstract code where I can add `data[i][j]` as I see fit.

Comment: I suspect you need to read of the numpy basis.  For example we index an element with `data[i,j]` and a column with `data[:,j]`. We can easily sum over rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time trying to figure if you were trying to get a scalar value or a column/row vector from the sums but here is how I would try to get either:

To get a row vector from:

`data = np.array([[327, 137, 82], [301, 168, 75]])`,

you can use `np.sum(data, axis=0)` which will return a row vector containing the sum of all elements for each column.

To get a column vector (it will be 1-dimensional) I would use:

`np.sum(data, axis=1)`, which will return a column vector containing the sum of all elements for each row.

To add a column with another column:

`data[:, 0] + data[:, 1]` would work.

Sorry if I am telling you the wrong thing, I can't tell if you are wanting a scalar or a vector as a result.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I am looking for a scalar. So for example, I want to add [327] and [301], but more generally, I want to do it abstractly.

Comment: @Ksant040 By abstractly, do you will have to search for the value first? Or will you already have the location? (ie. already having i1, j1 and say, i4, j4 as the locations of the scalars to be added)

Comment: I want to be able to input any array and the function accurately picks the values I want based on my criteria